# Efficient access of ordered results in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling

I am trying to translate a relatively common requirement in SQL to an efficient data model in Cassandra. I'm trying to decide how best to model my data so that I can order my rows in Cassandra in the same order that I wish to report them in the application. Normally this would be a good case for a clustering column, except that the data by which I want to order my result is a metric that will be updated several times daily.

I am going to explain the problem in SQL and then share what data modeling approaches have occurred to me. What I would like to know is, has anyone faced a similar requirement to mine and, if so, how did you model the data in Cassandra.

Here's the problem I'm trying to solve.

Suppose I have a raw_data table defined like so:

```
CREATE TABLE raw_data (
  A varchar,
  B varchar,
  C varchar,
  D varchar,
  ts timestamp,
  val varint
  PRIMARY KEY (ts,A,B,C,D)
);
```

And I also have a summary table

```
CREATE TABLE summary_table (
  A varchar,
  B varchar,
  C varchar,
  total_val varint
  PRIMARY KEY (A,B,C)
);
```

Where the data in my summary table is aggregated by my application in a way that corresponds to

```
SELECT A, B, C, SUM(val) FROM raw_data GROUP BY A, B, C
```

What I want to be able to do is execute a query like the following:

```
SELECT B, C, total_val FROM summary_table WHERE A = "Something" ORDER BY total_val DESC LIMIT 1000;
```

That is to say, I want to subset my summary table for a particular value of A and then return the top 1000 rows, ordered by total_val

Total_val is updated every few minutes by my application, as additional data are streamed into my raw_data table. So I can't use total_val as a clustering column for my data

What I'm trying to decide is how best to model this type of problem in Cassandra -- one in which I need to subset a summary table with a WHERE CLAUSE and order the result set (which are being updated constantly) in DESC order.

Some of the result sets can be expected to be fairly large -- several hundreds of thousands of rows (that is to say, there are some values for A in my summary table for which `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM summary_table WHERE A = "some value"` would be very, very large, in the hundreds of thousands). It's obviously inefficient to sort these data and discard prior to sending to my application.

Also, this doesn't seem to be a good use case for secondary indices. On smaller result sets, they are very performant. For larger ones, they are lagging and I suspect there may be a better way to handle this problem.

Another way I've considered modeling this involves caching the larger result sets into memory, so that at least where I would need to sort many thousands of rows, I'd at least be doing so in memory. I've also considered having a secondary summary table that's already prepopulated with the top 1000 rows that I want to expose to my application... although I can't think of a good way to keep those data up to date and avoid the exact same problem I'm having with my original summary table.

Has anyone encountered a problem like this, one in which you need to filter your summary data with a WHERE clause and order your (frequently changing) results in Desc order? If so, have you found a way to make this performant when certain WHERE clauses would return many thousands of rows? If so, how did you go about doing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way I can think of to do this would be the following:

```
CREATE TABLE summary_table (
  time_bucket long,
  A varchar,
  total_val int,
  timestamp long,
  B varchar,
  C varchar,
  PRIMARY KEY ((time_bucket, A), total_val, timestamp, B, C)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (total_val DESC);
```

With this structure, you don't actually overwrite `total_val`. Instead, you insert a new row for each new value, then discard all but the latest timestamp at query time.  The value of `time_bucket` should be your timestamp rounded to some interval you can calculate at query time (you may have to query multiple buckets at a time, but try to limit this to only two if possible). In case you're wondering, `time_bucket` and `A` become your partition key, which prevents unbounded row growth over time.

In other words, you've turned your summary table into time-series data.  If need be you can add a TTL to the old columns so they die off naturally.  As long as your time buckets are sane, you won't run into the issue of querying large numbers of tombstones.

Comment: "you've turned your summary table into time-series data...." This is really a brilliant idea, Robbie. I owe you a beer next time ATL Cassandra Meetup comes around. I'm thinking of about 20 different ways to apply something like this.... this is absolutely a fantastic idea.

Comment: Glad to be of assistance! Actually a general principle for modeling data with Cassandra is to write immutably. Remember that Cassandra is log-structured storage, so you just convert your data to what amounts to log data, which is time-series.